# Could not load file or assembly issue after installing Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR Nuget Package

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have an asp.net web forms application. It contains multiple projects and third-party dlls. One of the dlls is using log4net version 1.2.9.0 whereas other projects and dlls are using log4net version 1.2.10.0 and as a result, there is an error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.9.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b32731d11ce58905' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I see this error when we build the application but even then my application runs perfectly.
Now I need to implement SignalR in this application. After installing the NuGet package for SignalR, I get 500 - Server Internal Error and when I go into the details of error by putting httpErrors attribute in `web.config` file.

```
httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough"
```

I get error details on the page.

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.9.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b32731d11ce58905' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Kindly help me resolve the issue.

I have tried resolving log4net issue by putting  the following

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="b32731d11ce58905" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.9.0" newVersion="1.2.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>"
```

but it did not work, probably, publicKeyToken for both versions is different

Comment: I tried following <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="b32731d11ce58905" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.9.0" newVersion="1.2.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>          but it did not work, probably, publicKeyToken for both versions is different

Comment: I have not yet even created owin startup class, i just wanted to compile and run web application after installing SignalR package to make sure all is good

Comment: Try to reinstall your packages. Open Package Manager Console and use this command 'Update-Package -reinstall' . It will automatically reinstall all packages and missing files will be downloaded.